# Serve another server on the local network

Tags: apache-httpd

I have a Raspberry (say `pi-1`) running an apache2 web server that serves to the internet (`my.domain`).  I have a second Pi (`pi-2`) also running apache2 that serves to the local network over it's local IP address (`192.168.1.100`).  Is there a way to configure a subdomain of `pi-1` - e.g. `sub.my.domain` - that relays requests on to `192.168.1.100` and responses back to the client?

Answer (score 4):

You can setup apache on the first board with a virtual host entry that matches the sub-domain, and uses the `mod_proxy` module to send the request on to the second board.  See the example at
[apache virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html#proxy)

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/" "http://192.168.1.100/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://192.168.1.100/"
    ServerName sub.my.domain
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks @meuh. Does this go in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`?

Comment: I dont have apache on a pi, so I cannot say, but it goes in with the other configuration directives. But you really must read the linked-to page, and look up each of the directives above (ProxyPass and so on) so you understand what is going on. My answer is just a starting point.